# Counting two different values for each year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which includes Years and Genders. Here is an example of my table:

```
YEAR   Sex
1999    M
1999    M
1999    F
1999    F
```

I use this query for taking my result.

```
SELECT YEAR,COUNT(*)
FROM athlete_events
WHERE SEX = 'M'
GROUP BY YEAR;
```

And I see this result on output:

```
YEAR  COUNT(*)
1999         2
```

However I want to see this result:

```
YEAR  COUNT_MALE  COUNT_FEMALE
1999           2             2
```

Is that possible in Pracle SQL?

Answer (score 7):

You can do conditional aggregation with a case expression:

```
select year,
  count(case when sex = 'M' then year end) as count_male,
  count(case when sex = 'F' then year end) as count_female
from athlete_events
group by year;

      YEAR COUNT_MALE COUNT_FEMALE
---------- ---------- ------------
      1999          2            2
```

The count function ignores nulls, so rows that don't match the specified flag (which default to null in the case expression; you can have an explicit `else null` if you prefer) are not counted.

(Personally I prefer to use `count()` rather than `sum()` for this sort of thing as that better reflects what you're actually doing - counting things.)

Comment: Awe, thank you a lot. It gave me different point of view. You are awesome.

Answer (score 6):

You need *conditional* aggregation :

```
select year,
       sum(case when SEX = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as count_male,
       sum(case when SEX = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as count_female
from athlete_events
group by year;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are awesome.

Answer (score 4):

You can do subqueries, something like this:

```
SELECT 
  E.YEAR,
  (select count(*) from athlete_events M where M.YEAR=E.YEAR and M.SEX='M') COUNT_MALE,
  (select count(*) from athlete_events F where F.YEAR=E.YEAR and F.SEX='F') COUNT_FEMALE
FROM athlete_events E
GROUP BY E.YEAR;
```

This is more expensive (performance-wise) than conditional aggregation, on the other hand maybe easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Awe, you are awesome. Thank you a lot. It helps a lot.