# SUM(condition) in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm just curious: I know something like

```
SUM(string = 'anyString') over (partition by ANY_COLUMN)
```

or

```
SUM(string like 'anyWildcard%') over (partition by ANY_COLUMN)
```

is working in MySQL/MariaDB. What would be the equivalent in Oracle?

Comment: The SQL standard provides the [`FILTER` clause](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) for this, but I believe Oracle doesn't implement it yet. The alternative is to use a `CASE` condition in the `SUM`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70100706/1509264 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/51746115/1509264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ANSI/ISO SQL standard way is to use `case` *expressions* to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
SUM(case when string = 'anyString' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ANY_COLUMN)
```

**Standards compliance note:**

Using a `case` expression is **Core SQL** functionality, i.e. expected to work on *any* dbms.

`FILTER` is an optional feature of the ANSI/ISO SQL standard. '*Without Feature T612, “Advanced OLAP operations”, conforming SQL language shall not contain a < filter clause >.*'

Comment: The SQL:2003 and higher standard way is to use the [`FILTER` clause](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter), though it is not yet widely supported.

Comment: I know about that _optional_ feature, and I like it. But AFAIK, only Postgresql supports it.

Comment: PostgreSQL and SQLite support `FILTER`: https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

Comment: [Firebird 4.0](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/4_0/rlsnotes40.html#rnfb40-dml-filter-clause) and higher support it too.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `CASE` expression, either with `SUM()`:

```sql
SUM(CASE WHEN tring = 'anyString' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ANY_COLUMN)
```

or, for brevity, use `COUNT()`

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN tring = 'anyString' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ANY_COLUMN)
```

The second version achieves the same as the first, since the `COUNT()` function counts `NULL` values as zero, and the default `ELSE` for a `CASE` expression (not having an explicit `ELSE`) is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for showing the `COUNT` version. I think this is much cleaner since it doesn't need an ugly `ELSE` clause.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, I prefer the SUM() version, to avoid the '_Null value eliminated in set function_' warning you get from the COUNT version.

Comment: @jarlh I think writing ugly code to avoid useless warnings is a bad idea, but of course, that's kind of taste. There's nothing wrong with writing `ÈLSE...` but I dislike writing unnecessary else clauses. By the way, Oracle seems to do not show such a warning, see https://dbfiddle.uk/X0AugpE4 If I change the RDBMS in the fiddle to SQL Server, the warning appears ;)

Comment: I should also note that even if SSMS happens to show this warning, it would not be visible or an issue when calling SQL Server through an obfuscation layer like JDBC (i.e. calling from Java).

Answer (score 2):

MySQL/MariaDB are the only SQL databases that treat boolean expressions as 1 or 0 integer values. This is not standard SQL. But it allows tricks like using `SUM()` on a boolean expression, which is equivalent to counting the rows where the expression is true.

In Oracle or any other database, you can map a boolean to an integer this way:

```
SUM(CASE string WHEN 'anyString' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ...
```